# Is there a way to customize log stream prefixes on AWS Cloudwatch?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch

I'm tailing my AWS lambda function logs with the following command:

```
aws logs tail /aws/lambda/xxxx-processor --follow
```

And here's the output:

[image]

As you can see, 80% of the window is taken by long prefixes such as `[32m2020-04-06T03:07:49.049000+00:00[0m [36m2020/04/06/[$LATEST]d0e21ba6ec6c409a9a162ee9f9419b88[0m 2020-04-06T03:07:49.049Z        5f86c727-2b69-437d-840b-a28ba186b7ef    INFO`.

Is there a way to make it shorter when using `aws logs`?

Comment: One method is to post process the logs with tools like `awk`. https://www.tim-dennis.com/data/tech/2016/08/09/using-awk-filter-rows.html